# Book recommendation for matrix pseudoinverses?

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation, pseudoinverse

Can any of you recommend a solid book on generalised matrix inverses, specifically the Moore-Penrose inverse? I have a good background in linear algebra, but little in numerical methods and i was wondering where i could read up on this topic. It doesn't have to be a book dedicated solely to this, just as long as it has a section/chapter on the MP inverse. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Read section $4.9$ in this book, expecially proposition $4.9.2$.  This proposition deals with some properties of Moore-Penrose inverses

> [Linear algebra: Peter Petersen ( Springer)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461436117)

---

Also Read Appendix $D.5$ in this book, it deals with Generalized (Moore–Penrose) Inverses

> Linear Algebra: Seymour Lipschutz and Marc Lars Lipson

Comment: @Vigen ch: Just googling this title because there is a free pdf availlable

Comment: Thanks, i'll be sure to check these out!